# Get all the richTextBoxes and load textfiles with the same name

Tags: c#

On a form i have many richtextboxes. When the form loads i want to populate the richTextBoxes with text from txt files. For each richTextBox i have a text file and the name of the file is the same as the richTextBox name.
I tried this but it is not working because a component has no loadfile function ?

How can i load a lot of files into different richtextBoxes when a form loads?

```
private void getAllRichTextboxen(string aFileName)
        {
           foreach(Control item in this.Controls)
            {
                if (item is GroupBox)  //first get the groupboxes, all the richTextBoxes are within a groupBox
                {
                    foreach (Control aControl in item.Controls)
                    {
                        if (aControl is RichTextBox)  //check if it is a richTextBox
                        {
                            if (aControl.Name == aFileName)  //if the controle name = the same as the file name then load the file into the RichTextBox
                            {
                                aControl.LoadFile(Settings.applicatiePad + Form_Main.QueryMap + "\\" + aFileName + ".agq", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText));

                                //richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName,  RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply select all controls with type RichTextBox and set its Text Property:

```
foreach(RichTextBox r in this.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>())
    r.Text = File.ReadAllText(Settings.applicatiePad + Form_Main.QueryMap + "\\" + aFileName + ".agq");
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not get it. The foreach does not find a richtextbox. The location of the richtextboxes is tabcontrol->tabcontrol->groupbox->richtextbox.
the foreach only finds the first tabcontrol.

Is there a way to find ALL the components on a form?